# How can I pause multi-file copy when one is working?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I started a small project for fun and I liked it so much I started to expand it. I needed a simple file explorer (like windows one) to just see and open files but now expanding it I have a problem with multiple files, I want to copy some from directory A and paste them in B then while doing it I want to copy some files from directory C and paste them in D and if the copy A -> B is in progress the copy C -> D is paused and when the copy A -> B finishes the second copy can start. For now, I can copy files from A to B. Is there anything not too complex I can try?

I'm using a new form to display the progress bar, file name, file count, and size when starting a copy and I'm using a BackgroundWorker

Comment: What is the actual question? How to queue operations so they are run one at a time?

Comment: @JonasH Yes, and maybe how to properly handle a history of files to copy. For now, the best I did was a List<string> with full path (w/ filename) in it and when I paste I use filestream and I use the list to copy the files but I'm sure this is not the best idea to handle a history

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are just calling `File.Move` or `File.Copy` those don't give the ability to pause the actual operation, you will have to write your own Move/Copy operations

eg. to copy the file you could do the following

```
public void CopyFile(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite)
{
    var outputFileMode = overwrite ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.CreateNew;

    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(destFileName, outputFileMode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        const int bufferSize = 16384; // 16 Kb
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead;

        do
        {
            bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead == bufferSize);
    }
}
```

Now that you have this code you can simply add a `while` loop with a condition to "pause" the code eg.

```
while (_pause)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

This `while` would go into the `do` loop from the above code.

Here the complete idea

```
public void CopyFile(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite)
{
    var outputFileMode = overwrite ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.CreateNew;

    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (var outputStream = new FileStream(destFileName, outputFileMode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        const int bufferSize = 16384; // 16 Kb
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead;

        do
        {

            //run this loop until _pause = false
            while (_pause)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }


            bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead == bufferSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am assuming you are just calling File.Move or File.Copy" no, filestream. switched yesterday because was way better.
while (_pause) How is _pause set?

Comment: `_pause` is just a field that you will have to set upon a button click I assume

Comment: Since I close the progress bar form when it completes the copy I can use Worker_RunWorkerCompleter => _pause = false (that's not the code I'll use btw)

Comment: I gave you a general idea how this can be accomplished if you want to have a 100% solution which you would just need to copy&paste I am afraid to say I would need more information how you are currently doing stuff, since I know to little about your code I simply cannot tell you how/where to call it

Comment: Well, I need a better way to handle files history but... I have a progressbarwindow form and when I click copy in the contextmenu it saves the full file path in a List<string> then in paste I do 

new ProgressBarWindow(itemsToCopy //List<string>, fileFolder // source. i remove the file name later, filePath.Text, false //overwrite);
I can send the code somewhere, I don't know how to do it here.
P.s. Your [input/output] stream doesn't work, the progress bar never gets updated nor it writes something

Answer (score 1):

You could use objects to represent different operations, something like

```
public interface IFileOperation {
    void Execute(Func<double> ReportProgress, CancellationToken cancel);
}
```

You could then create a queue of multiple operations, and create a task on another thread to process each item

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
public double CurrentProgress {get; private set;}
public void CancelCurrentOperation() => cts.Cancel();
public BlockingCollection<IFileOperation> Queue = new BlockingCollection<IFileOperation>(new ConcurrentQueue<IFileOperation>());
public void RunOnWorkerThread(){
     foreach(var op in Queue .GetConsumingEnumerable()){
         cts  = new CancellationTokenSource();
         CurrentProgress  = 0;
          op.Execute(p => Progress = p, cts.Token );
     }
}
```

This will run file operations, one at a time, on a background thread, while allowing new operations to be added from the main thread. To report progress you would need a non-modal progress bar. I.e. instead of showing a dialog you should add a progress bar control somewhere in your UI. Otherwise you would not be able to add new operations without cancelling the current operation. You will also need some way to connect the progress bar to the currently running operation, For example by running a timer on the main thread that updates the property that the progress bar is bound to. You can either run the method as a long Running task, or as a dedicated thread.

You could, if you wish, add a pause/resume method to the FileOperation. The answer by Rand Random shows how to copy files manually, so I will skip this here. You could also create a UI that will show a list of all queued file operations, and allow removing queued tasks. You could even, with some more work, run multiple operations in parallel, and show separate progress for each one.

Comment: I don't need a pause/resume (at the moment). I had a form for the progress bar but looks like it's a bad option, I can delete it and add a progress bar to the main form and I need to find how to implement everything correctly

Comment: @code9 That question is kind of broad. Rand Random demonstrated how to do a manual file copy. This answer shows how you can queue operations for background processing. If you are asking specifically how to create a non modal progress-bar I would suggest posting a new question, or try it yourself and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I can do and try like I did until now, I can ask for some tips if you have any now